# Do I need to use OAuth just to pull tweets onto my site?

Tags: twitter

I'm having trouble pulling tweets onto my site. I just want to put my latest tweets on there so don't think I need a token but am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need OAuth - check out Twitter's [documentation](http://support.twitter.com/entries/15354-about-twitter-badges-and-widgets) for putting a widget on your site.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can just fetch it by querying the twitter API.  For example to fetch all tweets from Twitter support, visit http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=support

For more details, see [the documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline)

Answer (score 0):

You can also pull the data in via RSS. Click the "RSS" link from your browser to get the URL, it's your numeric twitter id which is not posted elsewhere.